# How do you upload a file from a server to a client in C?

Tags: c

I need to do this function:
put X Y : uploads the local file X to the server and names it Y at server side

I already wrote everything needed to set up the connection, I only want to know how to upload a file.
I only know the `send()` function which has 4 parameters, but it just seems to send an array of characters. How do you send an entire file, like an image for example?

Using HTTP, on Windows.

Comment: This question implies that you don't understand the difference between a file and it's contents. You want to send the file contents which are bytes.

Comment: So I just use the send function? How?

Comment: If the server speaks HTTP, FTP (etc...) you should use some HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Notice that your question is operating system specific (standard C11 does not know about sockets)

Comment: To send something to the server you can use `write()` or `send()`. Using `write()` is simpler because it is 'universal' file descriptor functions. `send()` is a more specialized function (you can ignore SIGPIPE, etc).

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I will show a example using `write()`. Using `send()` is similar. So, if you want to write a file to server:

 - Prepare all the socket setup as you have already mentioned;
 - Send the file. You must open the file and get a file descriptor to it. Also, you must have the socket fd in hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

1. Open the local file with `open()` for reading i.e.

   ```
   int fd = open(localFileName, O_RDONLY);
   if (fd == -1)
       errorFileCantBeOpenedForReadingAbortThis();
   ```
2. Read bytes from the file and write them to the socket

   ```
   int size;
   unsigned char buffer[SOME_REASONABLE_SIZE];

   size = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
   if (size == -1)
       aReadErrorHandleIt();
   if (write(sockfd, buffer, size) == -1)
       aWriteErrorHandleIt();
   ```

   do this in a loop until all the data was written.

In the server side, you need to write the data to the file that was probably specified through the `put` command or some custom command you might specify.

Of course you should first send the destination file name to the server along with something that indicates that a file write is about to start and open the file for writing.

It would be good if the server notifies the client that the writing might start and then the client could start writing until you send something to indicate that it was all sent, and the server could then close the file.

Comment: So I just the function send() or read() in a loop?

Comment: @terminator847 pretty much, sure there is of course a lot more to take care of, but the file copy will be performed this way, you could also send the file size to the server so it can check if the transmission was finished. That would be the hard part in fact, how to know when to start and when to stop sending/recieving.